# How to share data Internet connection of Android Galaxy A01 with Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, android, tethering

I've activated the Wi-Fi hotspot on the phone, connected to it with Ubuntu. Link is up, there is an address assigned, can ping the IP of the phone, the phone has Internet via mobile data, but no Internet connection from the Ubuntu.

```
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:2a:31:40:76:e9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.96/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 3600sec preferred_lft 3600sec
    inet6 fe80::7e2a:31ff:fe40:76e9/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How to find what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On the phone go to Settings -> Connections -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names -> select SIM you want -> click on the access point name you use, edit APN type: add ",dun" at the end. Mine looks like "default,dun".
2. Tap the menu button on top right and tap Save. It should restart the data connection.
3. Try to use hotspot. If it doesn't work then continue.
4. Delete all other access point names on the phone.
5. Try to use hotspot. If it doesn't work then continue.
6. Enable developer mode on the phone.
7. Install adb on the Ubuntu (`sudo apt install adb`).
8. Connect the phone via USB to the PC.
9. Run `adb shell` in the PC. The phone will ask to allow debugger connection. May need to confirm several times before getting into the shell.
10. In the shell run the command: `settings put global tether_dun_required 0`
11. Try to use hotspot. If it doesn't work then continue.
12. Restart the phone.
13. On the phone in the APN settings verify again that there is "dun" in the APN type.

[Source from Google support forums "Nexus 5(android 5.1) creates hotspot but no internet access"](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu18DRVyGHFAdjA)